# trying to train deepdoctection model

Tags: python, deep-learning, azure-databricks

Im trying to train my model on two dataset `publaynet` and `doclaynet`, so scaled my `doclaynet` images here is the logic:

```
df = doclaynet.dataflow.build(split="train", load_image=True)

scaler = ScaleTransform(h=1025,w=1025,new_h=2339,new_w=1654,interp="bilinear")

df = dd.MapData(df, scale_transform(scaler,True))
df.reset_state()

for idx, dp in enumerate(df):
    print(f"processing: {idx}")
    path = dd.get_dataset_dir_path() / "testpng" / dp.file_name
    cv2.imwrite(str(path),dp.image)
```

Next then i tried merging my both datasets:

```
doclaynet.dataflow.categories.set_cat_to_sub_cat({
dd.LayoutType.caption: dd.DatasetType.publaynet,
dd.LayoutType.footnote: dd.DatasetType.publaynet,
dd.LayoutType.formula: dd.DatasetType.publaynet,
dd.LayoutType.list: dd.DatasetType.publaynet,
dd.LayoutType.page_footer: dd.DatasetType.publaynet,
dd.LayoutType.page_header: dd.DatasetType.publaynet,
dd.LayoutType.figure: dd.DatasetType.publaynet,
dd.LayoutType.section_header: dd.DatasetType.publaynet,
dd.LayoutType.table: dd.DatasetType.publaynet,
dd.LayoutType.text: dd.DatasetType.publaynet,
dd.LayoutType.title: dd.DatasetType.publaynet})

doclaynet.dataflow.categories._categories_update = [dd.LayoutType.text,
                                                        dd.LayoutType.title,
                                                        dd.LayoutType.list,
                                                        dd.LayoutType.table,
                                                        dd.LayoutType.figure]

df_doc = doclaynet.dataflow.build(split="train",resized=True)   # requires to create resized images
df_doc_val = doclaynet.dataflow.build(split="val",resized=True)  # requires to create resized images
df_doc_test = doclaynet.dataflow.build(split="test",resized=True)  # requires to create resized images

scaler = ScaleTransform(h=1025,
                            w=1025,
                            new_h=2339,
                            new_w=1654,
                            interp="bilinear")

df_doc = dd.MapData(df_doc,filter_list_images)
df_doc = dd.MapData(df_doc, scale_transform(scaler))

df_doc_val = dd.MapData(df_doc_val,filter_list_images)
df_doc_val = dd.MapData(df_doc_val, scale_transform(scaler))

df_doc_test = dd.MapData(df_doc_test,filter_list_images)
df_doc_test = dd.MapData(df_doc_test, scale_transform(scaler))
df_pub = publaynet.dataflow.build(split="train",max_datapoints=25000)
merge = dd.MergeDataset(publaynet)
merge.explicit_dataflows(df_doc, df_doc_val, df_doc_test, df_pub)
merge.buffer_datasets()
merge.split_datasets(ratio=0.01)
```

then i started my training session with registered weights and my config file:

```
import os
from deepdoctection.utils import get_configs_dir_path
path_config_yaml=os.path.join(get_configs_dir_path(),"/dbfs/mnt/ocr/data_set/ocr-dataset/config/conf_dd_one.yaml")

path_config = dd.ModelCatalog.get_full_path_configs('layout/d2_model_0829999_layout.pth')
path_weights = dd.ModelCatalog.get_full_path_weights('layout/d2_model_0829999_layout.pth')
categories = dd.ModelCatalog.get_profile("layout/d2_model_0829999_layout.pth").categories
coco = dd.metric_registry.get("coco")

dd.train_d2_faster_rcnn(path_config_yaml,
                        merge,
                        path_weights,
                        ["SOLVER.IMS_PER_BATCH=2", "SOLVER.MAX_ITER=240000", "SOLVER.CHECKPOINT_PERIOD=4000",
                         "SOLVER.STEPS=(160000, 190000)", "TEST.EVAL_PERIOD=4000", 
                         "MODEL.BACKBONE.FREEZE_AT=0",
                         "WANDB.USE_WANDB=True", "WANDB.PROJECT=layout_detection"],
                         "/dbfs/mnt/ocr/template1_invoice/template-2-test",
                         None,
                         merge,
                         None,
                         None,
                         coco,
                         "ImageLayoutService")
```

But im getting this error can anyone help me solve this error?

[image]